# Python CaesarCipher IndexError

Tags: python

Running python 3.5.
I'm start a study of basic encryption and I decided to try my hand at writing a simple Caesar cipher. Pretty straight forward logic:

1) for a given plaintext message, find the index for each message symbol in my LETTERS string

2) add the shift key to the index

3) the resulting number is the index of the cipher symbol

4) if the resulting number is greater than the length of my LETTERS string, then subtract the length of the LETTERS string from the number (this handles the wrap around back to the beginning of the string.

So here is the code for that program.

caesarCipher2.py

```
LETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrustuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()><.,?/"

message = str(input("Enter a message. "))
key = int(input("Enter a whole number key (1-79). "))
mode = str(input("Press 'E' to encrypt or 'D' to decrypt. "))


def encrypt_message(plain_message):
translated = " "
for symbol in plain_message:
    if symbol in LETTERS:
        num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
        num += key
        if num > len(LETTERS):
            num -= len(LETTERS)

        translated += LETTERS[num]
    else:
        translated += symbol
return translated


def decrypt_message(cipher_message):
translated = " "
for symbol in cipher_message:
    if symbol in LETTERS:
        num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
        num -= key
        if num < 0:
            num += len(LETTERS)

        translated += LETTERS[num]
    else:
        translated += symbol
return translated


def main():
if mode == "E" or mode == "e":
    print(encrypt_message(message))
elif mode == "D" or mode == "d":
    print(decrypt_message(message))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Program seems to work ok, however as I'm running test cases, I start noticing that some shift keys are throwing an IndexError at the following line of the encrypt_Message():

```
translated += LETTERS[num]
```

So I decided to write another script, using the code from the encrypt_Message() to test any given message for all possible keys. What I found was that any plaintext message I pass through the function will result in a few of the shift keys (usually 5 - 10 keys) throwing an IndexError at that same line. All the rest of the keys return the ciphertext as intended.

Debugging the code on these error throwing keys shows me that some point in translating the plaintext message for these specific keys, the line:

```
num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
```

returns the length of LETTERS instead of the index of the symbol within LETTERS and then the code seems to hang up from there. The if statement doesn't fire off to adjust the num variable and so by the time it reaches the translated statement, the num variable is index out of bounds.

My question is why is this happening? Why is the code working as intended for the majority of the keys, while throwing this exception for the remaining?

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is with your check "if num > len(LETTERS)". It should be "if num >= len(LETTERS)" because if it is equal to the length of the list, it is out of bounds.

Comment: I think @Byteventurer is onto the problem, but can you paste the exact traceback for a situation that throws the exception.  Tracebacks are your friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python indexes lists starting at 0. This will have the following effects:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> len(x)
4
>>> x[0]
'a'
>>> x[3]
'd'
>>> x[4]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Notice that `x[4]` is already out-of-scope for a list with 4 elements. As a rule of thumb, the maximum index that can be considered inbounds is `len(x) - 1`.

In your case, the mistake is

```
if num > len(LETTERS):
```

which should be

```
if num >= len(LETTERS):
```

Comment: This is why I love you guys. I've been debugging this thing off and on for a couple of days now and I overlooked that completely. Thank you for the fresh set of eyes.